# Jupyter Notebook not giving proper Output format

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter Notebook not giving proper Output format, it is not aligned

[image]

Comment: You need to select a fixed font if you expect your columns to be aligned.  You are using a variable-width font.

Comment: and this question is more about pandas styling than jupyter https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.